# Database table is not creating, onCreate is not called

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
public class ProductOrderHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ckredisDB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;
/* ALL COLUMNS */
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCT_ORDER = "order_products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_ORDER_ID = "orderId";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID = "productId";
/* ALL COLUMNS ARRAY */
private String[] allColumns = {
        COLUMN_ID,
        COLUMN_ORDER_ID,
        COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID
};

// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_PRODUCT_ORDER + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_ORDER_ID + " integer not null, "
        + COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID + " integer not null);";

private SQLiteDatabase database;

public ProductOrderHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX orderId_index ON " + TABLE_PRODUCT_ORDER + "(" + COLUMN_ORDER_ID + ")", null);
    database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX productId_index ON " + TABLE_PRODUCT_ORDER + "(" + COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID + ")", null);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCT_ORDER);
    onCreate(db);
}
/* REPOSITORY THING */

private void open() throws SQLException {
    database = this.getWritableDatabase();
}
public long createEntry(ProductOrderModel e) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COLUMN_ORDER_ID, e.getOrderId());
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID, e.getProductId());

    this.open();
    long insertId = database.insert(TABLE_PRODUCT_ORDER, null,values);
    this.close();

    return insertId;
}
}
```

Then I'm trying to add new row:

```
prodOrdHelp = new ProductOrderHelper(this);
ProductOrderModel pm = new ProductOrderModel();
pm.setProductId(indexedProductIds.get(i));
pm.setOrderId(orderId);
prodOrdHelp.createEntry(pm);
```

EXCEPTION:

Error inserting orderId=2 productId=5231
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: order_products (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO order_products(orderId,productId) VALUES (?,?)

Also what I noticed, that method onCreate is never called ( even when I changed DATABASE_VERSION )... Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are completely wrong:

```
database.rawQuery("CREATE INDEX orderId_index ON '" + TABLE_PRODUCT_ORDER + "'('" + COLUMN_ORDER_ID + "')", null);
database.rawQuery("CREATE INDEX productId_index ON '" + TABLE_PRODUCT_ORDER + "'('" + COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID + "')", null);
```

1 - rawQuesry only executes QUERIES (which is "SELECT" statements and nothing else) not COMMANDS. You should use exexSQL, as in the line above these two.

2 - What are all those apostrophes (')? Remove them as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I corrected those lines as you said, but it didn't to call onCreate method

Comment: Well I'm not used to this funny datadase Helper syntax... I use the old school SQL commands (i.e.: "INSERT INTO MyTable (My, Columns) VALUES (My, Values)").

Comment: I don't think that it's a sintax problem... this.open(); or this.getWritableDatabase(); should fire onCreate method if table doesn't exist, but when I call this.open() and then try to insert something, I'm getting `Error inserting orderId=1 productId=5231
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: order_products (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO order_products(orderId,productId) VALUES (?,?)`, and when I tried to debug onCreate method, I noticed that it doesn't fire at all

Comment: The onCreate should fire when from the CALLING ACTIVITY you call **prodOrdHelp = new ProductOrderHelper(this);**

Comment: But it doesn't ... I have 'Log.i("ProductOrderHelper", "Creating database");' in onCreate method and it's not firing... :( Even when I delete all app data on my device